# Using route in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, routes

i need to route urls like in zf1.

in particular i need that these urls will be automatically redirect to appropriate actions without specify a new route every time.

```
/site/getData
/site/getData?param=5&par2=test
/site/getOther
...
```

So a segment route doesn't work, i've tried a Literal route but i can't reach a working solutions.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This should be solved by a pretty default segment route like the one provided in the documentation.

```
'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
'options' => array(
    'route' => '/:controller[/:action]',
    'constraints' => array(
        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
    ),
    'defaults' => array(
        'controller' => 'default-controller-alias',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ),
)
```

Now if you set up your controller names like the following:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'sites' => 'Namespace\Controller\SitesController',
        'other' => 'Namespace\Controller\OtherController'
```

Then you should be able  to achieve exactly what you want. And to create params to your route, you simply use the ViewHelper correctly ;)

```
$this->url('routename', 
    array(
        'controller' => 'site',
        'action'     => 'getData'
    ), 
    array (
        'query' => array(
            'param1' => 'foo',
            'param2' => 'bar',
            'paramN' => 'baz',
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: This code will work for only index Action and will forbidden other Action

Comment: forbidden action? This has NOTHING to do with access control

Comment: The problem with Segment is when i put query string parameters like this:

Comment: @Sam is effectively right. 

You can create generic routes that examine the *request path*. These can be general enough so that you do not have to add a new route for each action. 

However, AFAIK, you cannot specify different routing on the query string. You'd have to create one action and then forward - *not redirect* - to different actions based upon the query string values.

Also, AFAIK, this is no different than ZF1.

Comment: @fasi91 Modified the answer ;) Check again

Comment: mmm...no. If i use a segment route, when i go to site/getdata?param=5 i obtain a 404 error because it not match the regex defined for action

Comment: @fasi91 The error is somewhere on your side. I have created a testproject and this works just fine. Post your complete router config and i'll see about it.

Comment: Ok yes, is my error...i've just found it...So for any other visitor the Sam's solution works fine :) Thanks!